# SELECT2: Slow render with only 220 items in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

So my framework is passing an array with 220 items to my templating engine (Smarty). Upon page load the form is rendered pretty quickly up until the 220 item dropdown. When it reaches that dropdown it takes 5-6 seconds before it's rendered, freezing the page and all non-rendered items below it.

My HTML/Smarty is:

```
{html_options class="form-control select2-render" id="category" name="category" data-search="true" options=$categorylist selected=$selectedcategory}
```

Then in my JS I have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2-render').select2();
});
```

I'm running the latest release from Github (4.0.12) with jQuery 3.4.0.

Even a list of just 50 items takes about a full second to parse after the page has been loaded. Am I doing something wrong?